# How can i save my result persistently?

Tags: android, persistence

How can I save the value of `contadorliga` or turn `.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` even if I restart the app or I close the app and start it again (persistent storage)?
I want to save `int contadorliga`, `correcto1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` and `correcto2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` so each time I restart the app it is as the latest time it was. Like as a save game.
This is my code:

```
package com.fakur.android.futbolquiz;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Liga extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

static final int LIGA = 0;
int contadorbarcelona = 0;
int contadormadrid = 0;
int contadorliga = 0;

ImageView about;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.liga);
TextView contador1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contador1);
contador1.setText(contadorliga + "/20");
}

public void onBarcelonaClick(View botton) {

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(this,Pregunta.class);
intent.putExtra("Barcelona", "Barcelona");
startActivityForResult(intent,LIGA);
}

public void onMadridClick(View botton) {

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(this,Pregunta.class));
intent.putExtra("Madrid", "Madrid");
startActivityForResult(intent,LIGA);
}
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

TextView contador1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contador1);
ImageView correcto1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.correcto1);
ImageView correcto2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.correcto2);

if (requestCode == LIGA){

if (resultCode == 1) {

    if(contadorbarcelona == 0){

      correcto1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      contadorliga++ ;
      contadorbarcelona++;
    }
}

if (resultCode == 2) {
    if(contadormadrid == 0){

       correcto2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       contadorliga++ ;
       contadormadrid++;
    }
}

}

contador1.setText(contadorliga + "/20");

}
```

Comment: You can use the Shared Preferences: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by rciovati, SharedPreferences are better to use that database as it will lead to performance issue if you want to retrieve this data from database again and again.

There are other options available for storing persistent data in android app. check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Answer (score 0):

YOu can use database to save that data u want permanently stored